# Io exception: Connection refused(DESCRIPTION=(TMP=)(VSNNUM=168821248)(ERR=12505)(ERROR_STACK=(ERROR=(CODE=12505)(EMFI=4)))) error

Tags: java, jdbc, jakarta-ee

Yesterday i was using oracle 9.1 with ojdbc 14 jdbc driver with following code for adding employee, it was working fine but now i am using oracle 10.1.0.2.0 with ojdbc14 but now it is giving following error

```
Io exception: Connection refused(DESCRIPTION=(TMP=)(VSNNUM=168821248)(ERR=12505)(ERROR_STACK=(ERROR=(CODE=12505)(EMFI=4)))) error
```

Following is code for adding employee

```
public static Connection getConnection() throws Exception {
    String driver = "oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver";
    String url = "jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:5500:globldb3";
    String username = "scott";
    String password = "tiger";
    Class.forName(driver);
    Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url, username, password);
    return conn;
  }
public String addEmployee(){
    Connection conn = null;
    PreparedStatement pstmt = null;
    boolean committed = false;
try {
    conn = getConnection();
    conn.setAutoCommit(false);
    String query = "INSERT INTO  
employee(e_id,e_name,e_f_name,e_desg,e_address,e_phone_no,"+        
"e_salary,e_house_rent,e_conv_allow,e_email,d_name,e_hire_month,e_hire_year)"+     
"VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";      
    pstmt = conn.prepareStatement(query); 
    pstmt = conn.prepareStatement(query); // create a statement
    pstmt.setInt(1,this.eid); 
    pstmt.setString(2,this.ename);
    pstmt.setString(3,this.efname);
    pstmt.setString(4,this.edesg);
    pstmt.setString(5,this.eaddress); 
    pstmt.setLong(6,this.ephoneno); 
    pstmt.setInt(7,this.esalary);
    pstmt.setInt(8,this.houserent);
    pstmt.setInt(9,this.convallow);
    pstmt.setString(10,this.eemail); 
    pstmt.setString(11,this.edname);
    pstmt.setInt(12,this.ehmon);
    pstmt.setInt(13,this.ehy);
    pstmt.executeUpdate(); // execute insert statement
    conn.commit();
    conn.setAutoCommit(true);
    committed = true;
    return "add-employee-msg.xhtml";
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return "add-employee-ex.xhtml";
    }   finally {
            try{
                if (!committed) conn.rollback();
                if (pstmt != null) pstmt.close();
                if (conn != null) conn.close();
            }catch(Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
}
}     //addEmployee
```

Any idea please?

Comment: error 12505 is wrong SID. Make sure you have the SID right.  Thin driver need to connect via TCP.

Comment: @J-16 SDiz:I am sure that my sid is rite.What do you mean by thin driver need to connect via TCP?kindly explain

Comment: I changed the ojdbc14 driver with latest ojdbc 14 driver from oracle.com, now i am getting "ORA-12505, TNS:listener does not currently know of SID given in connect descriptor
The Connection descriptor used by the client was:
localhost:1521:globldb3
" error

Comment: I changed the port no from 1521 to 5500 because it was the port no with which oracle 10g was first opened in browser now i am getting    "Io exception: The Network Adapter could not establish the connection
"

Comment: My listener.ora file was having port 1521 so i changed port 5500 with 1521, now i am getting    "ORA-12505, TNS:listener does not currently know of SID given in connect descriptor"

Comment: please see my question it is similar to this only https://stackoverflow.com/q/45284753/6303688

Answer (score 2):

That's a configuration issue:

> 12505, 00000, "TNS:listener does not currently know of SID given in connect descriptor"

Maybe you just have to copy the original `LISTENER.ORA` (correct name??) to your new oracle instance. You use the sid `globldb3` which may be undefined on the 10.x instance.

Comment: Thanks for your time.Sir would you please further explain your last two lines?

Comment: @Adnan - each database has a unique *System ID (SID)*. `globldb3` is the sid of the 9.1 instance, your new oracle instance has (a) different sid(s). Look for the correct name and the connect string in your code

Comment: Ok.I have already deinstalled oracle 9.1.I am sure that sid for oracle 10.1 is globldb3.

Comment: @Adnan  - with the `Listener.ora` you tell oracle to accept connections from your actual client (ip address, symblic name)

Comment: How do we tell oracle to accept connections from your actual client?

Answer (score 2):

You have wrong DB URL.

You have: `"jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:5500:globldb3"`

But should be: `"jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:5500/globldb3"` <- notice slash instead of colon for the SID name.

Answer (score 1):

Due to wrong SID/Servicename this issue will arise. Based on Servicename/SID, need to correct DB URL, otherwise it will be showing Connection refused error.

format for both forms:
JDBC URL FORMAT: 
jdbc:oracle:thin:@//:/ServiceName 
or
jdbc:oracle:thin:@::

Answer (score 1):

#### JDBC URL FOR ORACLE, wrong or correct, how do you know?

- INSTANCE SID by ":"

  > jdbc:oracle:thin:@db_ip_or_name:1521:ODB_IS
- SERVICE NAME by "/"

  > jdbc:oracle:thin:@db_ip_or_name:1521/ODB_SN
- How do you know?

  > SELECT NAME,VALUE,DESCRIPTION
  >   FROM V$PARAMETER P
  >   WHERE P.NAME IN ('db_unique_name','db_name','instance_name','service_names');
  >   `*maybe you need your dba's help to query data dictionary view
  >   *----NAME-----|--VALUE--|--DESCRIPTION------------------------------
  >   instance_name | ODB_IS  | instance name supported by the instance
  >   service_names | ODB_SN  | service names supported by the instance
  >   db_name       | ODB_NM  | database name specified in CREATE DATABASE
  >   db_unique_name| ODB_UN  | Database Unique Name`
  >   The defferents are for RAC, DG; PRD,UAT,DEV deployment requirement etc.
  >   Use service_names = db_name as normal, they must been see in 'lsnrctl status'
- PORT:

  > `lsnrctl status`
  >   *run on the DB server shell window

Answer (score 0):

This should work :

```
<property name="connection.url">jdbc:oracle:thin:@//localhost:1521/ORCL</property>
```

Comment: please add some more explanation of your solution, and how it helps