# java.sql.SQLException when trying to connect to Oracle database

Tags: java, jdbc, oracle9i, ojdbc

My problem is that i attempt to connect to a remote Oracle database. Its version is 9.2.0.6, i use jdk 1.7 and ojdbc14.jar .

This is the code :

```
Connection connection = null;

    try {

        connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@//10.130.34.3:1522/myDB", "binette","Passer");

    } catch (SQLException e) {

        System.out.println("Connection Failed! Check output console");
        e.printStackTrace();
        return;

    }
```

And i got this error :

```
Connection Failed! Check output console
java.sql.SQLException: Exception d'E/S: Connection refused(DESCRIPTION=(TMP=)(VSNNUM=153093632)(ERR=12514)(ERROR_STACK=(ERROR=(CODE=12514)(EMFI=4))))
    at oracle.jdbc.dbaccess.DBError.throwSqlException(DBError.java:134)
    at oracle.jdbc.dbaccess.DBError.throwSqlException(DBError.java:179)
    at oracle.jdbc.dbaccess.DBError.throwSqlException(DBError.java:334)
    at oracle.jdbc.ttc7.TTC7Protocol.handleIOException(TTC7Protocol.java:3668)
    at oracle.jdbc.ttc7.TTC7Protocol.logon(TTC7Protocol.java:353)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleConnection.<init>(OracleConnection.java:371)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver.getConnectionInstance(OracleDriver.java:551)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver.connect(OracleDriver.java:351)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:571)
```

I tried to chande the jdbc jar to classes12.jar but it is the same error.
I have already search on internet but I can't figure out the problem.Any idea please?

Comment: Please refer following link.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6503144/io-exception-connection-refuseddescription-tmp-vsnnum-168821248err-12505

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like `ORA-12514: TNS:listener does not currently know of service requested in connect descriptor`(according to error code).
So maybe your service name isn't **myDB**?

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your database configuration  you should try

```
connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@//10.130.34.3:1522:myDB", "binette","Passer");
```

instead of

```
connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@//10.130.34.3:1522/myDB", "binette","Passer");
```

Comment: What is difference between two connection string??

Comment: Inthe first ine port and instance name are separated by ':', in the second one port and instance name are separated by '/'.

Answer (score 0):

I thinks its a firewall issue. Try to open the port **1522** in the firewall and then check.

Answer (score 0):

I have resolved my problem.So i wasn't connecting to the right database.Now the connection pass!thank you! :-)